# Can OpenTSDB align the start of the downsample interval with the query start timestamp?

Tags: opentsdb

I understand that the alignment of the downsample interval will align to the nearest natural calendar/clock boundary. So 1h-sum will align the start of the downsample to the top of the hour.

Is there a way to align it with the start specified by the query?

E.g. to specify start as '1d-ago', and downsample as 1h-sum and then get 24 aggregate data points aligned to the current time exactly. If 'now' is 2017-03-08 10:17:23, then the interval boundaries align with 17 minutes, 23 seconds past the hour.

Answer (score 1):

There are several cases where non-calendar alignment would be useful:

- Sliding averages/totals with endtime is reset to current time.
- Daily aggregations in a time zone, different from the server time zone.

This is how we implement aggregator alignment in [Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/) which also runs on HBase.

https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/f365c04e

Both the [SQL](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-docs/tree/master/api/sql#period) syntax, [Rest API](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-docs/blob/master/api/data/series/period.md), and the graphics library expose the `align` field which accepts the following options:

- `CALENDAR`
- `END_TIME`
- `START_TIME`

These options determine the start time for each period.

[image: Aggregator Alignment]